# R data.table last row index shortcut

Tags: r, data.table

In matlab, you can do something like

```
my_matrix[20:end]
```

which will get the 20th row to the last row in `my_matrix`. Is there a similar shortcut in `R data.table`? Something like:

```
my_matrix[20:end, ]
```

Comment: Have you considered using `.N`?

Comment: just Do tail(my_matrix, -19)

Comment: @Onyambu I think you could post that as an answer.

Comment: thanks. all I wanted was `my_matrix[20:.N, ]`

Answer (score 3):

One can access the rows and columns of a matrix in R with the extract operator `[`. Also, `nrow()` is the function that calculates the number of rows in a matrix or data frame. Here is an example that creates a matrix and accesses the last 5 rows and first 3 columns. We use `set.seed()` to ensure that the random number generator always generates the same results with `runif()`.

```
set.seed(95014123)
theData <- matrix(runif(2000),nrow=200,ncol=10)
# print last 5 rows, first 3 columns
theData[(nrow(theData)-4):nrow(theData),1:3]
```

...and the output:

```
> theData[(nrow(theData)-4):nrow(theData),1:3]
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.2028385 0.8105820 0.0171761
[2,] 0.4002767 0.9859544 0.7952463
[3,] 0.6723984 0.2401554 0.9591462
[4,] 0.3931757 0.4883088 0.2563899
[5,] 0.5325255 0.1430370 0.7674389
>
```

The `data.table` version using `.N` as noted in the OP comments looks like this.

```
library(data.table)
aDataTable <- as.data.table(theData)
# print last 5 rows, first 3 columns
aDataTable[((.N)-4):.N,1:3]
```

...and the output, which matches the other approach:

```
> aDataTable[((.N)-4):.N,1:3]
          V1        V2        V3
1: 0.2028385 0.8105820 0.0171761
2: 0.4002767 0.9859544 0.7952463
3: 0.6723984 0.2401554 0.9591462
4: 0.3931757 0.4883088 0.2563899
5: 0.5325255 0.1430370 0.7674389
>
```

Note that the `nrow()` approach also works with a data table:

```
aDataTable[(nrow(theData)-4):nrow(theData),1:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well.  I have been advised to post this as an answer.

```
tail(my_matrix, -19)
```

This gives you the desired output.